# Not getting WebRTC status chanegd to RTCICEConnectionConnected

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, libjingle, rtcpeerconnection

below are my steps:

1. Initialise webRTC
2. socket connected
3. onRenegotiationNeeded
4. addLocalMediaStrem
5. peerConnectionCreateOffer
6. didCreateSessionDescription
7. setLocalDescriptionWith SDP
8. send SDP to socket
9. RTCICEGatheringGathering
10. get local ICECandidates
11. received message from socket
12. RTCSignalingStable
13. RTCICEConnectionChecking
14. peerConnection?.setRemoteDescriptionWith SDP
15. received message from socket
16. RTCICEGatheringComplete
17. RTCSignalingHaveRemoteOffer
18. received remote media stream

but still not getting RTCICEConnectionConnected state. why is it so? what is missing?